# cast a varchar to date

Tags: sql, casting, h2

i use a H2 database for a small project, all field are varchar

for a query, i must convert a string to date so i tried

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE cast(DATE_CONTRACT AS DATE)  >  '2005-02-21'
```

but there are an error

Code :

> Error code 90009, SQL state 90009:
>   Cannot parse date constant
>   "2011-02-21-15.22.07", cause:
>   "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: ""21-15.22.07""";

any idea?

thanks

Comment: The extra dash between the date portion and the time portion is probably tripping up the conversion.

Comment: "cut" the fisrt 10 characters of the varchar and then cast?

Comment: or use `SELECT * FROM USER WHERE DATE_CONTRACT >= '2005-02-22-00.00.00'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use parsedatetime() in order to "cast" your character data to a date.

http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#parsedatetime

Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER 
WHERE parsedatetime(DATE_CONTRACT, 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss')  > DATE '2005-02-21'
```

Another good reason to never store dates, timestamps or numbers as character data

Comment: There is a typo in the format string (the quote is missing), and it doesn't completely match the problem (dots instead of colons): it should be `'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss'`

Answer (score 3):

Of course you could use the built-in function `PARSEDATETIME` as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE USER(DATE_CONTRACT VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO USER VALUES('2011-02-21-15.22.07');
SELECT * FROM USER 
WHERE PARSEDATETIME(DATE_CONTRACT, 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss') > DATE '2005-02-21';
```

But I guess it would make more sense to store the timestamp in a more standard format, so that no special parsing is required. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE USER(DATE_CONTRACT TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO USER VALUES('2011-02-21 15:22:07');
SELECT * FROM USER 
WHERE DATE_CONTRACT > DATE '2005-02-21';
```

H2 supports the [format supported by JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29), plus [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: it's sure... but there are too many system who use the db... so i can't change it...

Comment: Ok, so you would need to use PARSEDATETIME then. My vote goes to a_horse_with_no_name who first suggested that.

Answer (score 2):

Why convert to date? If DATE_CONTRACT uses a consistent CHAR(19), you can:

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER 
WHERE DATE_CONTRACT >= '2005-02-22-00.00.00'
;
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but if there is an index on `DATE_CONTRACT`, this will be faster than converting to date/datetime.

Comment: That's correct, such a date format can be sorted (except for negative or very large years).